# Number of solutions of a variable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
c & c & 1-c &  1\\
c & c^{2} & 1-c^{2}  & 1\\
2c & c+c^{2} & 2-2c  & c+2
\end{array}\right)$$

row reduced to:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
c & 1 & 0  & 1\\
0 & c-1 & 1-c &  0\\
0 & 0 & c+1 &  1
\end{array}\right)$$

question asks to find the values of 'c' for which the matrix has:

1. infinite solutions
2. one solution
3. no solution

my answer:

the column vectors are linearly independent thus the Rank[A|b] = Rank[A] = n = 3

then for all c ≠ 1 we have one solution

And for c = 1 we have no solutions.

Thanks,

Comment: You claim that: *the column vectors are linearly independent*. Is this true also for $c=0$? Is this true for $c=1$?

Comment: @MartinSleziak no, i've included that case in my answer.

Comment: The way you phrased it I thought that you claim this for any value of c. I do not see any mention of $c\ne0$ in the current revision of your post. Note that $(x,y,1)$ is solution of the original system for $c=0$, so in this case you have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: You have cancelled a factor $c$, which is only allowed if $c\neq0$

Comment: @Michael so would it be correct to say that for 0 we still have infinite solutions, since the only limitation on the variables if c=0 is that z = 1?

Comment: I don't the same row reduction as you – in addition to the simplification by $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let us look at the cases separately.

in case $c = 0,$ you have the system $\pmatrix{0&0&1&|&1\\0&0&1&|&1\\0&0&2&|&2}$ which is and has infinitely many solutions.

in case $c = 1,$ you have the system $\pmatrix{1&1&0&|&1\\1&1&0&|&1\\2&2&0&|&3}$ which has no solutions.

in case $c \ne 0, c \neq 1$ we can reduce 
$\pmatrix{c&c&1-c&|&1\\c&c^2&1-c^2&|&1\\2c&c+c^2&2-2c&|&c+2} \rightarrow
\pmatrix{c&c&1-c&|&1\\0&c^2-c&c-c^2&|&0\\0&-c+c^2&0&|&c} \rightarrow
\pmatrix{c&c&1-c&|&1\\0&c^2-c&c-c^2&|&0\\0&0&c-c^2&|&c}
$

has a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
(c \ne 0) \wedge (c \ne 1) \wedge (c \ne -1)
$$